# Computer has internet, most services won't work properly however some do. What is causing this and how to fix?

Tags: windows-7, networking, dns, ping, connection

sorry if this has been answered before but I am absolutely stumped, I've no idea why this computer is not working correctly. So let me lay out the events leading up to this issue and after that what has already been attempted.

There will be a lot of details so quick TL:DR
Computer has internet, can ping external places but not establish connections, should not be hardware issue as can perfectly fine run a working VM with internet on said non-functional device.

Now for the full explanation.

**Events leading up to breakdown:**

Network was fine, everything working normally I was watching a youtube video, went to help someone afk, when I came back the computer was like this, no one lives here but me and could have messed with it, the only noteworthy thing was BitDefender Free (Version before bitdefender moved to 30 day trials) had kicked off and started an auto scan which was weird as prior it was disabled.

**Now to what I have observed so far and troubleshooted:**
First some general observations:

1. Browsers are not letting me visit anything saying connection issue
2. Softwares on exception for Mumble(Void Software) are not able to properly connect to anything (Including BitDefender, Browsers, Steam...)
3. Windows 7 does not report a connection issue at all.
4. Firewall is fully disabled to try and resolve issue and I do not know of any other software present with a firewall that could do this.
5. After setting up a Virtual Box VM Windows 10 home eddition it is clearly able to connect and use the internet connection despite it's host being unable to. (Proof is the fact I am writing this on said virtual machine)
6. Several softwares reported that they are 'Unable to resolve localhost'
7. Team viewer (In lan only more and internet mode) is unable to get attached to the local interface. (Normaly would show id as teamviewer ID or 192.168.1.1 but is showing blank.)
8. Teamviewer is able to somehow know and accept my other pc is on 192.168.1.11 but not able to establish a connection between them. The other device also knows about the host PC (192.168.1.1) but is also unable to establish a link. (Seems like UDP based stuff is getting through as that is what mumble was using after it gives up on TCP connection.)

**Trouble Shoots:**

- Checked cable is pluged in => Yep.
- Tried different cable to rule out cable is the proble. => Still not working.
- Checked internet is available to other devices => Yes. -> Rules out router at fault.
- Checked via ping that internet is working correctly => Partial -> Ping with DNS does not work.
  Direct IP ping does.

**127.0.0.1 => Pinged fine**

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping 127.0.0.1

Pinging 127.0.0.1 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128
Reply from 127.0.0.1: bytes=32 time<1ms TTL=128

Ping statistics for 127.0.0.1:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 0ms, Maximum = 0ms, Average = 0ms
```

**localhost => Unable to reach**

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping localhost
Ping request could not find host localhost. Please check the name and try again.
```

**216.58.212.228 => Pinged fine**

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping 216.58.212.228

Pinging 216.58.212.228 with 32 bytes of data:
Reply from 216.58.212.228: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=116
Reply from 216.58.212.228: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=116
Reply from 216.58.212.228: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=116
Reply from 216.58.212.228: bytes=32 time=10ms TTL=116

Ping statistics for 216.58.212.228:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 4, Lost = 0 (0% loss),
Approximate round trip times in milli-seconds:
    Minimum = 10ms, Maximum = 10ms, Average = 10ms
```

**[www.google.com](http://www.google.com) => Unable to reach**

```
C:\Windows\system32>ping www.google.com
Ping request could not find host www.google.com. Please check the name and try a
gain.
```

- Restarted computer => No effect
- Restarted in safe mode => No effect
- Checked hosts file in C:Users/Windows/System32/Drivers/Etc/Hosts => Looks fine.

> 127.0.0.1  localhost

- Tried changing IPV4 DNS from AUTO to ISP servers => No Change
- Tried changing IPV4 DNS from ISP servers to Google Servers => No change
- Checked cmd IPCONFIG /All => Unsure if correct

```
Windows IP Configuration

   Host Name . . . . . . . . . . . . : DeathTech-PC
   Primary Dns Suffix  . . . . . . . :
   Node Type . . . . . . . . . . . . : Hybrid
   IP Routing Enabled. . . . . . . . : No
   WINS Proxy Enabled. . . . . . . . : No

Ethernet adapter VirtualBox Host-Only Network:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 0A-00-27-00-00-16
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::e521:306:6a89:9d8d%22(Preferred)
   Autoconfiguration IPv4 Address. . : 169.254.157.141(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.0.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . :
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 336199719
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-E1-46-70-00-26-2D-1E-7A-20

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : fec0:0:0:ffff::1%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::2%1
                                       fec0:0:0:ffff::3%1
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Ethernet adapter Local Area Connection 3:

   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Realtek PCIe GBE Family Controller
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 9C-5C-8E-7A-84-47
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
   Link-local IPv6 Address . . . . . : fe80::465:44a5:a0fe:a732%24(Preferred)
   IPv4 Address. . . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.1(Preferred)
   Subnet Mask . . . . . . . . . . . : 255.255.255.0
   Default Gateway . . . . . . . . . : 192.168.1.254
   DHCPv6 IAID . . . . . . . . . . . : 832330894
   DHCPv6 Client DUID. . . . . . . . : 00-01-00-01-17-E1-46-70-00-26-2D-1E-7A-20

   DNS Servers . . . . . . . . . . . : 8.8.8.8
                                       8.8.4.4
   NetBIOS over Tcpip. . . . . . . . : Enabled

Tunnel adapter isatap.{F2171A27-FB9C-4897-AA74-F8F78C2CF775}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #2
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes

Tunnel adapter isatap.{E18E7795-5658-4D77-A72A-401A8CFBE0AF}:

   Media State . . . . . . . . . . . : Media disconnected
   Connection-specific DNS Suffix  . :
   Description . . . . . . . . . . . : Microsoft ISATAP Adapter #5
   Physical Address. . . . . . . . . : 00-00-00-00-00-00-00-E0
   DHCP Enabled. . . . . . . . . . . : No
   Autoconfiguration Enabled . . . . : Yes
```

- CMD Ipconfig /dnsflush => No effect
- CMD Ipconfig /registerdns => No effect
- CMD Route /f => Broke everything restarted -> No effect
- CMD nslookup seems to be working though.

```
C:\Windows\system32>nslookup www.google.com
Server:  dns.google
Address:  8.8.8.8

Non-authoritative answer:
Name:    www.google.com
Addresses:  2a00:1450:4009:81f::2004
          216.58.212.228
```

- CMD  netsh int ip reset followed by ipconfig /flushdns => No effect.

```
C:\Windows\system32>netsh int ip reset 2>resetlog.txt
Reseting Global, OK!
Reseting Interface, OK!
Reseting Unicast Address, OK!
Reseting Route, OK!
Restart the computer to complete this action.

C:\Windows\system32>ipconfig /flushdns

Windows IP Configuration

Successfully flushed the DNS Resolver Cache.
```

**Conclusion so far:**

1. Internet is working fine between VM to outside so the issue is localised to HOST computer.
2. Host computer is not acknowledging an issue but UPD based softwares might still work (like mumble)
3. Part of DNS seems to not be working? Not sure why. I can ping IP's but not resolve Names but the inablility to resolve names seems to be partially working as nslookup is happy to find stuff for me.

Any ideas on how to fix or what to do to get connections to go through are welcome. Because as far as I can tell this pc should be working just fine but it is not.

Comment: What's interesting is that your system seems to be unable to resolve even `localhost`, which in Windows is handled completely internally to the OS and would generally work even without DNS. So I'd rather suspect the resolver, not DNS itself -- for example, is the Dnscache service listed as running (check in Task Manager or `sc query`)? Does BitDefender come with a firewall? Have you tried removing it completely?

Comment: Try TCP/IP Reset:   I did not see this in your post.   Open cmd.exe with Run as Administrator
(1) netsh int ip reset c:\resetlog.txt
(2) ipconfig /flushdns
(3) restart the computer  and test.

Comment: Too much weird stuff is happening. Since this happened recently, if System Restore is enabled on your computer, the best course would be to rollback to before this happened. Otherwise, a [Repair Install of Windows 10 with an In-place Upgrade](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/16397-repair-install-windows-10-place-upgrade.html) is indicated.

Comment: To user1686 Dnscache is running.  To John I will try that one next.  To Harrymc Sadly System Restore isn't an option as that broke long ago. If needed I might have to wipe the whole thing and upgrade to windows 10 but at this point I really require windows 7 for a bit longer. It is much preferred to keep this device at the current windows version.

Comment: @John tried what you said. When it came back online it had no internet. Diagnosed problem and DHCP was not enabled for the connection. After having it admin resolve it back to default settings the issue is still present.

Comment: All of DNS is not working. DNS is not used when you ping an IP directly. All your DNS queries have failed.

Comment: @DanielK I suspect you may be right which is strange as I can see things make contact to 8.8.8.8 and 8.8.4.4 when looking at resource monitor all software that are misbehaving are for some reason connecting from IPv4 Loopback (127.0.0.1/localhost) to the same. Never attempting to connect externally. Not sure why everything is only attempting to use localhost.

Comment: Although you can try to repair (see answer below), I think that it might be futile and this system will need to be rebuilt.

Answer (score 0):

You have tried the other suggestions without success. Now you need to do a Windows 7 Repair Install. A realistic Repair Install for Windows 7 is here:

[Windows 7 Repair Install](http://www.sevenforums.com/tutorials/3413-repair-install.htmlhttps://)

You need the Windows 7 DVD for your system do this.

> You can only do a repair install with the same edition Windows 7
> installation disc for the same edition of Windows 7 that you have
> installed. You cannot use a OEM Windows 7 "Factory" Restore/Recovery
> type of installation disc that came with or created from a store
> bought computer to do a repair install with. These can only be used do
> a clean install instead. You can do a repair install on a factory OEM
> installation with the latest official Windows 7 with SP1 ISO file
> here: Microsoft: Windows 7 Direct Download Links, and use Windows 7
> USB-DVD Download Tool to create a bootable DVD or USB flash drive with
> the ISO to do the repair install from within Windows 7. You can use a
> retail OEM Windows 7 installation disc to do a repair install with.
> You can use a retail (full or upgrade) Windows 7 installation disc to
> do a repair install with.

Start with the Windows 7 DVD and select Repair.

If you do not have the Windows 7 DVD or if you find the Repair Install for Windows 7 daunting (it is), then now is the time to consider upgrading to Windows 10. Much easier to repair and manage.